# In-app Purchase "ready to submit", but won't let me submit it

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have some in-app purchases setup for an application.  The in-app purchases are all tested, and working great - however I can't submit them for review.  I submitted the application binary for review, then visited the in-app purchase section.  All of the in-app purchases say: "Ready to Submit", but the "Submit for Review" button is greyed out, and un-clickable.

When apple reviews the actual application, will they also just review the in-app purchases for it?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

**Update:  I don't know if it was by switching to Chrome, or by waiting 30 minutes or so, but it enabled me to submit my in-app-purchases for review.**

Comment: I have a same problem. I can't submit in-app purchases.

Comment: +1 for saying that you tested with "Ready to Submit." I had been submitting this stuff for review, which MAY be why it wasn't allowing me to test.

Answer (score 87):

I was having the same problem. It would not let me submit my In app purchases to my app, which I uploaded shortly beforehand. I had to reject the binary, then follow the directions below to add the IAP to the app version before uploading.

1. Go to iTunes Connect
2. Click on Manage your applications
3. Click on the App
4. Click "View Details" button
5. Scroll down until you see an "In App Purchase" Section
6. Add your In App Purchase to that version.
7. Then ready your app for upload.

Once these steps are complete, the In App Purchase should **automatically** change from "Ready to Submit" to "Waiting for Review".

Comment: wtf ? really ? I thought it's enough to just add a new app version. Damn it. I created an update of an old app (1 week of work) because I thought this is what I need to do to get the iap up and running. Now that old app has been approved and I still don't have iap because I failed to "add the app purchases to that version". Why did they sepearte creation and linking onto 2 different pages. I'll try your steps soon. Hopefully it will work this time. I really want to start testing IAP to finally finish my new App. Apple makes me go crazy sometimes !

Comment: THanks for that answer. Worked fine after following your suggestion.

Comment: Step 6 is critical, must be done before step 7. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: To clarify, once you click "ready to upload binary", this forbids you from adding IAPs to the version.  Also, it seems the "Submit for Review" button for the IAP itself is always grayed out - I think this is just poor design and not intended as a button.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, the state of the app within itunes connect was wrong. I had to **upload the binary** then go to the **binary details** panel and **reject this binary** before I was able to see the check marks in the inapp purchase section of the app summary.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that needs to be checked first before submitting an app with in-app purchase :

1. Enable in-app feature in your "Identifiers -> App IDs". This is
   usually automatically enabled by Apple by default
2. Ensure the    correct link from your "Provisioning Profile" to the "App IDs"
   above, which has in-app feature
3. Build your file with the correct    "Provisioning Profile".

Before you update the binary, you must set up the in-app in iTunes. Goto the :

1. "Manage In-app Purchases", and add/setup your pricing,    description, etc in there. If you don't see this, then you will need     to create a new version of your app first.
2. Once done, it will    change to "Submit Binary File"

Now, update the new version description and select the correct in-app that you just created.
Upload the binary file to Apple using Xcode, and status should change to "Waiting for Review".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  For me the solution was simple.  I was using Firefox and couldn't see the checkboxes to submit the purchases.  Simply switch from Firefox to Chrome and you'll see the boxes again to check off and submit.

Answer (score 1):

It's been more than a decade since this question was opened. It is ridiculous that Appls IAP submission is still confusing. [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180741/609345)'s answer saved my ass, I just would like to make minor updates to keep it up to date, and hope it will save others' time.

If you missed to submit an IAP, and the App is already in the wild, prepare for a new submission. If you cannnot submit an IAP, and your App was already submitted/approved, just reject it. After you get a new binary uploaded, do the following:

1. Go to App Store Connect
2. Click on My Apps
3. Click on the App
4. Click "In-App Purchases" under the "Features" section on the left side, make sure your IAPs are ready for review
5. Click "Prepare for Submission" under the top-left "iOS App" section
6. Scroll down until you see an "In App Purchase" section
7. Add your IAPs to that version
8. Add your binary to that version
9. You are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

Use the "View Details" button and go to the bottom of the page, in the "In-App Purchases" section use the link "Manage In-App Purchase", do "Select All" and submit any no. of products for review along with the binary.  Additional in-app products can be added from the Application summary "Manage In-App Purchase" button using the table provided.

Comment: I can not see the "Manage In App Purchase" section in the version details (it is available on the top, app summary only). Does it disappear once "Waiting for Review"?

Comment: No they are still here during "Waiting for Review"