# Submitting iPhone app to the App Store with in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

I have an iPhone app ready to submit to App Store.

The app contains an in-app purchase to unlock some features. What extra things to be taken care of when we submitting app with in-App purchase?

Comment: thanks for help actually i have not tried yet to submit but before submitting i want to make sure that what i am doing is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to refer to this link:

[In-app Purchase "ready to submit", but won't let me submit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088560/in-app-purchase-ready-to-submit-but-wont-let-me-submit-it)

You may like to refer to Ran's answer there which is as stated below:

I was having the same problem. It would not let me submit my In app purchases to my app, which I uploaded shortly beforehand. I had to reject the binary, then follow the directions below to add the IAP to the app version before uploading.

> 1. Go to iTunes Connect
> 2. Click on Manage your applications
> 3. Click on the App
> 4. Click "View Details" button
> 5. Scroll down until you see an "In App Purchase" Section
> 6. Add your In App Purchase to that version.
> 7. Then ready your app for upload.

Once these steps are complete, the In App Purchase should automatically change from "Ready to Submit" to "Waiting for Review".

Apart from this, we need to follow all the same steps as we do in case of normal iPhone app.

Answer (score 1):

remember to upload an in app purchase image in the inapp section else you will be rejected.