# Not able to submit in-app purchase products to Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have just created an iPhone application and submitted it to Apple Store. The application have been approved by Apple and is available in Apple Store. The application uses in-app purchase. I had tested the in-app purchase using test user account.

Now I want to submit the in-app purchase products for review. The status of these products is ready to submit in itunesConnect. When I open up these products, I can see the button Submit for Review but it is grayed out i.e, it is disabled. Now how will I submit the in-app purchase.

I have downloaded the application from Apple Store but when I open it, it crashes probably because the in-app purchase haven't been submitted as yet. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you signed all the relevent contracts? They get updated by Apple and you need to accept the updated terms. Take a look on iTunes Connect under the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" section.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Try Safari also check out this SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088560/in-app-purchase-ready-to-submit-but-wont-let-me-submit-it

Comment: I have tried it on safari and chrome. But I am not able to see anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upload a version and delete it from iTunes Connect then only I was able to submit the  in-app purchase products.