# In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review.

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am in a bit of a pickle here.

I added a new version for my app as I added IAP to it.
I've added the IAP item in the "Manage In-App Purchases" menu in the new version section.
However I forgot to select the IAP item to be added in the New Version "View Details" page.
So I rejected the binary hoping the option to select the IAP item to reappear. But no it does not appear anymore. All it says is:

> In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has
>   already been submitted for review. To manage your In-App Purchases, go
>   back to the App Summary page and click on the Manage In-App Purchases
>   button.

So what to do now?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but here goes.

Seems like the only time you will be able to select an IAP item in the "View Details"
page of your app's new version is when the App Status is in "Ready to Upload Binary" or "Binary Rejected".

So what I did was reject my binary and deleted the IAP item and then add the IAP item again in Manage In App Purchases. Need to give it a new ID though, but no biggie for me.

After that, you should be able to select the IAP item in View Details page.
And THEN, press "Ready to Upload Binary"...

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hello I'm facing the same problem right now. So it means that I have to wait until my app is rejected by Apple? Or I could reject the App my self? where to? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah you have to reject binary your own app. It is in Manage Your Applications -> Go to your app -> click on the right side app (where you update)->Then there should be a "Binary" link at the top right. Click that and there will be a "Reject This Binary" button.

Comment: Gentle reader, do not make the same mistake that I have by rejecting the binary, then clicking on Ready to Upload straight away. Now I am forced to upload again only to reject it, just so I can enable the sodding IAPs.

Comment: I could manage without deleting by following http://stackoverflow.com/a/6180741/119031

Answer (score 4):

I found very strange Steps for it...

- Upload your binary
- Wait until it's "Waiting for review"
- Reject the binary yourself (app version > binary details >reject binary)
- Wait until it's "Developer rejected"
- Go add your in app purchases
- Resubmit the binary

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the status is not waiting for upload, if so, upload a binary then reject it.

You don't need to delete the IAP item.

After that, you should be able to edit the In-App Purchases section of your app.