# Adding a in-app purchase while "Waiting For Upload"

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing my first app which contains an in-app purchase. The app is tested and working fine. My in-app purchase is "Ready To Submit" in iTunes Connect and my app status is "Waiting For Upload". I have not yet submitted a binary for this app.

When I select the first (and only) version of my app in iTunes Connect (which is "Waiting For Upload") and scroll down to the "In-App Purchases" section, I see the following message: "In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review. To manage your In-App Purchases, go back to the App Summary page and click on the Manage In-App Purchases button."

I'm thinking I should be seeing the in-app purchase that I have set up listed in that section. Is it possible that it has been left out because I selected "Ready To Upload Binary" **before** I added the in-app purchase to iTunes Connect? I've read through Apple's documentation and can't find any reference to this problem.

I want to know that the in-app purchase will be available when the app goes live. Do I need to back track from "Waiting For Upload" in order to add it? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366184/in-app-purchases-cannot-be-added-to-this-version-because-it-has-already-been-sub)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366377/700769

I submitted a binary and then rejected it myself. My app status changed to "Developer Rejected" and I was able to add the in-app purchase as intended.