# What i need to do after finish test in-apps purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am ready to upload binary to Apps store, but i am confuse.

I should upload binary to apple and wait for review without in-apps ?

or I can upload binary and in-apps at the same time?

Anyone can show me the correct way to upload the apps to apps store with in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app uses IAP (In-App Purchase) then you HAVE TO declare the IAP in iTunes Connect and add the IAP that you use in the application details (in iTunes Connect) . You must first create (declare) the used IAP identifiers and then go to your app description (details. Where you also write the description of the app, upload screenshots , etc ) and add the IAP identifiers that you declared.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks George, I have already done all of your advise, and i want to know where to go after the above have done. Is click submit the IAP first then Upload the binary? or something else?

Comment: If you declared the IAP in iTunes connect and you added them in the application details , you are ready to upload the binary from this point of view. The IAPs will get approved the same time as the app does.

Comment: That means I only need to upload the binary and the IAPs will automatically change state to waiting for review?

Comment: Yes , submit the IAP too , again , make sure you add the IAP in the app details (can't stress enough the importance of this step ) and if everything looks ok you are ready to upload the binary

Comment: i.e. Submit binary -> Submit IAP -> Waiting for review?

Comment: Here , this answer writes down all the steps needed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6180741/624091

Comment: Thank you George! I got the answer now.