# What to submit first: in app purhcase or app binary?

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I remember once I had a problem sending an in app purchase product before uploading the app binary for approval at iTunes Connect, or vice versa.

I know that if I do it in the wrong way, I have to set your in app purchase again and start all over. Can someone help me understand the exact order to this? Which one of them should I do first?

Comment: This is the exact question I was about to ask. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rant, you can click "Ready to Upload Binary", and then submit the app binary for approval, that any in app purchases you have will follow the statuses of the app (Waiting for review, in review..).

For more details, check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180741/675486