# What is the binary to submit with In-App Purchase that I failed to include that caused it to be rejected?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My first In-App Purchase for an app has been rejected by Apple with the following Notes from App Review:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We have returned your in-app purchase products to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the in-app purchase products with the binary.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Learn more about offering in-app purchases in App Store Connect Help.

What is the binary to submit?

When I click on my In-App Purchase, the English (U.S.) localization had a red dot beside it, and the App Store Promotion 1024x1024 image had a yellow outline around it. I changed the wording of the Display Name and replaced the 1024x1024 image with a different one, and the In-App Purchase says Waiting for Review afterwards.

[What to submit first: in app purhcase or app binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308849/what-to-submit-first-in-app-purhcase-or-app-binary) says it should say "Ready to Upload Binary" and [In-app Purchase “ready to submit”, but won't let me submit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088560/in-app-purchase-ready-to-submit-but-wont-let-me-submit-it/6180741#6180741) says I should be able to add the In-App Purchase in the app submission, but neither of those options are available to me.

Do I submit the app now without adding the In-App Purchase to it? Is the In-App Purchase already automatically included with the app submission from the last submission when I added the In-App Purchase?

There doesn't appear to be stack**overflow** post that has current information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to upload the new binary with new version of the app. While doing so you will get an option to include the In-App Purchases to add along with new version of the app. Select all the In-App Purchases that you want to be reviewed.

Comment: I am not seeing the place to add In-App Purchases, and I've already added the build to the app submission before submitting.

Comment: I guess you got it. I work as an iOS developer. If you need some professional help in some projects please let me know.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the offer.